# Government Root CA installed on computer/browser and Man-In-The-Middle

Tags: man-in-the-middle, certificate-authority, root

Some countries already have their government Root CA installed on computer/browsers. Is it possible for these countries to read Google etc. mails by using Man-In-The-Middle or similar technique(s)?

Comment: Yes, that's the entire point.

Comment: Have you tried removing it? :)